# 16.04 install failing on old W7 Lenovo

Tags: 16.04, windows-7, lenovo

I've been an Ubuntu user for several years, but I'm an end user not a developer. I was having problems with the old laptop I've been using so I decided to install 16.04 on my wife's old Lenovo PC, which had W7. I can run Ubuntu from the USB OK but when I tried to install it with the replace Windows option the installation process crashed.

Windows no longer boots, but this isn't a problem for me. I've attempted the installation several times but it keeps crashing with error

> `ubiquity crashed with signal 7 in FT_Stream_ReadFields()`.

I'd appreciate some help with this and will of course share any additional info that's needed to diagnose & solve the problem.

Comment: I guess that it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it may be a bad live version of Ubuntu. I'd suggest doing a checksum of the ISO and then recreating the live USB. Here's a
[guide](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/how-to-verify) on how to verify your ISO

Comment: Thanks - I've had a look at the guide but it's too technical for me - I have no "basic knowledge of the command line, checking of SHA256 checksums and use of GnuPG". I followed the instructions on the Ubuntu download page to get the ISO. Perhaps I should repeat this process?

Comment: @stm146 Yes, you should download it again, just in case. The DownThemAll addon for Firefox makes it easy to download and checksum in one go. Use Rufus from Windows or MKUSB from Ubuntu to burn the ISO top the USB flash drive.

Comment: Rufus is nice because it has a built-in checksum button.

Comment: Update - I've downloaded & installed 16.04 several times now & when I try to boot from the hdd I get a 1962 error, "No Operating System found". Also, although 16.04 runs fine from the USB, when I try to shut down I get a black screen but the PC remains powered up.

Comment: Thanks - I downloaded the ISO again & used MKUSB to get it on the USB drive. The install seemed to work, but I when I try to boot from the HDD I get error 1962 - no operating system found. I've downloaded the ISO & reinstalled several times since but I still get the same error. I've tried installing with SATA configured as AHCI and as IDE but the same problem arises in both cases. Ubuntu runs fine from the USB, but when I try to shut down the screen & PC stay powered up, though the screen is black & the keyboard & mouse don't seem to do anything.